# Using ArcGIS Pro raster statistics functions to calculate percent of pixels with range of RGB values?

Tags: raster, spatial-statistics, arcgis-pro

Working in ArcGIS Pro 2.0 for this task.  I am fairly inexperienced working with raster functions.  I am trying to utilize a raster clip of a parking lot from NAIP 1m imagery.  Essentially, this process will compare the percentage of pixels in the clip which are asphalt as compared to the percentage which are not.  Asphalt will be defined using a range of pixels in each band. 
 For example pixels which fall within these bounds for all three layers would be considered asphalt, while the rest would not:

- Red 100 to 155
- Green 105 to 160
- Blue 105 to 140

I am not sure what functions to look for.

How can I construct this process?